# NextJS fetch giving an error when calling API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, strapi

I have a component defined as:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { getNavBarLogo } from "../lib/website";

export async function NavBarLogo() {
const data = await getNavBarLogo();

  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        className="h-18 w-auto"
        src={data.props.logo}
        alt="Logo"
        height={40}
        width={40}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also have the function `getNavBarLogo()` as:

```
export async function getNavBarLogo() {
  const query = qs.stringify(
    {
      populate: { SmallLogo: { fields: ["url"] } },
    },
    {
      encodeValuesOnly: true,
    }
  );

  const res = await fetch(
    env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL + "/website" + "?" + query,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_TOKEN}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(res.statusText);
  }
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(env.API_BASE + data.data.attributes.SmallLogo.data.attributes.url)
  return {
    props: {
      logo: env.API_BASE + data.data.attributes.SmallLogo.data.attributes.url,
    },
  };
}
```

Everything appears to be functioning, but the Chrome developer tools are showing the following:
[image]

Why is it trying to read from localhost?  I provide an API URL and a token.  I'm not understanding what the errors are telling me.

Comment: Where this env variable is defined?

Comment: On my machine?  in the `.env.local` file.  In Azure, it will be an environment variable in the web app.

Comment: I was aking, shouldn't be `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL`?

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't I get be getting an unknown on `env` and not the outcome.  Also, the image is populating, so it's reading the environment variables and returning the image url, just also giving me a ton of errors in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your envs are undefined. try setting them /accessing them correctly, possibly from the process.

Comment: They are not undefined.  The URL is being pulled and the image is populating.